# How long can a foreign registry glider stay in the US before having to change the register to N or having to leave the country?

Tags: glider, aircraft-registration

This is a qualification on a previous question, specifically for gliders.
[Here is the link](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95654/how-long-can-a-foreign-registry-airplane-stay-in-the-us-before-having-to-change) to the answer to the more generic question. Juan Jimenez thanks for the answer there.

As other sources suggest different, I wonder whether there is somewhere a explicit mention about gliders or at least an explicit mention that aircraft can stay in the US indefinitely.

I researched [Code of Federal Regulations](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-91/subpart-H) and did not find an explicit mention that foreign registered aircraft may stay in the US indefinitely.
Hence I wonder.

How to be sure?

Comment: Do not use GPT for regulations or anything legal-related, it makes up a lot of nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no explicit mention of this anywhere. The conclusion that foreign aircraft can remain in the US indefinitely is based on it not being forbidden anywhere, not it being explicitly allowed. Gliders are no different than any other aircraft in this regard.