Can you fly a newly EASA type certified aircraft in the USA?
If you get an aircraft that has just been issued a type certificate by EASA, can you fly it within USA in the same category right away? I'm reading about Bilateral Agreements and it seems that the answer would be yes, but I'm confused because for example the Pipistrel Velis Electro was certified more than 4 years ago by EASA yet it doesn't have the same category(only as experimental) in the USA.
How does this process really works?
What's the point of having a bilateral agreement? (it seems as if the FAA has to re-work everything EASA already did)

A starting point for an answer: EU - USA Bilateral Agreement

I can't find the answer to the question in that link...

Type certificates go through an easier process of recognition but there is no automatic recognition.

There are several separate issues here, and this will be lengthy but only partial answer to your question.
A type certificate issued in any ICAO country permits flying into and within any ICAO country. So an aircraft that has type certificate in EASA can fly into USA right away - but it cannot be registered in USA before FAA grants an American type certificate. So an European airline can acquire a brand new EASA certified aircraft type and begin to operate to USA, but a US airline has to wait until the said aircraft type is type certified by FAA until beginning to operate it.
An aircraft cannot be registered in a country that does not recognize the type certificate granted by another authority. This issue has been prominent in Europe with aircraft from former Soviet countries. For example, many Eastern European countries have historically approved Russian type certificates. That means several Russian built aircrafts exist and are registered into these countries. Even though they are now EASA countries, the aircrafts' registrations cannot be transferred under other aviation authorities as these nations have not approved Russian type certificates - even within EASA. This also prevents aircrafts only certified in Europe to be registered in USA.
Commerial operators have on top of that additional international hurdles. Airlines operators certificate granted by the local authority dictates where the aircrafts' operated by the airline have to be registered. As a general rule, an airline cannot acquire an aircraft registered in another region and begin to operate it at different area. So an US airline cannot by default operate an aircraft that has been registered in Europe. Some aviation authorities allow exemptions on this, but that is up the local authorities.
Finally there is the matter of traffic rights. These are called "Freedoms of the Air". By default, the most basic of them such as overflying another country and a right to land for a technical stop are in force between all ICAO nations.
There are nine of them, and it is up to the nations to agree which ones are applied between them. These are called Bilateral agreements.
You can view all the freedoms here: https://www.icao.int/Pages/freedomsAir.aspx
But basically, to obtain the type certificate in EU, USA, China etc. the manufacturer has to repeat the entire process with the said authorities - at least on paper. Some type certificates may even require addition test flights under supervision of the said authority. In practice, especially FAA and EASA type certificate requirements are pretty well harmonized but not identical. But maybe somebody else can shed light on the actual process (and pricing!)

So, that means according to what you say and this https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/95669 that I can purchase and register the aircraft in Europe, fly it to USA, and simply fly it indefinitely in USA just renewing my EU registration whenever needed.
